# ruby on rails search based on zip codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple search query that returns list of buildings based zip codes. The zip codes are stored in address table with a one to one relation on buildings and address. Now I need to search the buildings based on multiple zip codes.

```html
<input type="text"
       name ="fs_Zip[]"
       class="input-small text-tip"
       data-original-title="Enter Zip Code to search."
       placeholder ="Zip Code"/>
```

this is the code in my view. and in controller

```rb
buildings = buildings.where('address.zip in (?)', params['fs_Zip'])
if (!params["fs_Zip"].blank? && params["fs_Zip"] != 'zipcode')
```

But it does not give desired result. Any help.

Comment: Fix you question. That looks really wired.

Comment: Agreed. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: How building and address is related?

Comment: I need to find buildings based on multiple zip codes. e.g if i give 15649 and 15648. how would i do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your query should look something more like this:

```
buildings = Building.joins(:address).where('addresses.zip in (?)', params['fs_Zip'])
```

But you need to make sure `params['fs_Zip']` is in the proper format for that query (i.e. an array of zips).

Comment: using the `?` syntax with `where` should handle sql injection issues

Comment: Great yeah wasn't sure about that.

Comment: ya that's where I am stuck, do I provide an autopopulate to search through zipcodes like in gmail, where users can select multiple zipcodes and in turn I can return them or is there is any other way to do it

Comment: There are lots a ways to handle the user input, but that is more of a design question (checkboxes, tags, autopopulate, etc).